# Passing Data from One SQL Script to Another

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a script - `config.sql`:

```
 IF '$(EnvName)' = 'Env1'
    -- Call 'doStuff.sql' and pass in some data, like 'EnvName = Env1'
```

In `doStuff.sql`:

```
 -- I want to define/accept the parameters
 SET EnvName = @EnvName - inbound data - no idea what the syntax should be
```

I know this is super fundamental but I can't seem to find any examples.  Is this possible?

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to write a comment but it seems that I don't have enough points to do that...

Anyhow, based on the excerpt you provided I take it you use SQLCMD to run the SQL scripts. If that is the case then you can use `-v` switch to define parameter you want to pass to the execution.

For further information, please have a look at SQLCMD syntax in [sqlcmd Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) and [Use sqlcmd with Scripting Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx)